# RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'description

Tags: python, django

I perform request http://167.71.57.114/api2/workout-exercises/3
I want to receive data about `WorkoutExercise` object number 3 (detail view)

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `description` on serializer `ExerciseSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'description'.

**serializers.py**

```
class WorkoutExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = ExerciseSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = WorkoutExercise
        fields = ('week', 'exercises')
```

**views.py**

```
class WorkoutExerciseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = WorkoutExercise.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkoutExerciseSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
```

**models.py**

```
class WorkoutExercise(models.Model):
    workout_program = models.ForeignKey(WorkoutProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='workout_exercises')
    week = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    day = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            last_order = WorkoutExercise.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('order'))['largest']
            if last_order is not None:
                self.order = last_order + 1
        return super(WorkoutExercise, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_workout_programs(self):
        return self.workout_program.name

    def get_exercises(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.workout_program.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('week', 'day')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that `exercises` is plural, and `RelatedManager` error, it means that there are *multiple* `Exercises`, so you need to serialize these with a `many=True` parameter:

```
class WorkoutExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = ExerciseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkoutExercise
        fields = ('week', 'exercises')
```

Comment: Dear Willem, could you please look at ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66976783/importerror-cannot-import-name-user